# Python Selenium: Click on button based on text inside span tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to click on this button when <Span text is "OK":

```
<button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" style="float: right;"><span>OK</span></button>
```

The soluton would be something like that (this code don´t work because it´s not clickable):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="OK"]').click()
```

I found a way that works, but I can´t garantee the text inside Span is "OK":

```
button =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > section > section > div.ant-row > div:nth-child(2) > div.ant-spin-nested-loading > div > div > div > div > div.ant-collapse-content.ant-collapse-content-active > div > div > div > div:nth-child(17) > button.ant-btn.ant-btn-primary')
button.click()
```

How can I click on buttons based on Span tag?

Edit:
[Button code line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpHKb.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, based on your button `HTML`

```
<button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" style="float: right;"><span>OK</span></button>
```

I think that the following `xapth` would help you.

```
//button[contains(@class, 'ant-btn-primary')]//*[contains(., 'OK')]/..
```

The `/..` helps you traverse back 1 level; sending you to the main button. 
In order to search for the "OK" text in a `span`, you need to use the `node` / period search. Which is why I did `//*[contains(., 'OK')]`.

To find this button and then click on it, you would do the following

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'ant-btn-primary')]//*[contains(., 'OK')]/..").click()
```

**ALTERNATE XPATH**

```
//button[contains(@class, 'ant-btn-primary') and contains(., 'OK')]
```

And you would click on the button as such

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'ant-btn-primary') and contains(., 'OK')]").click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both solutions worked. I liked your explanation about the "/..", it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no reason why `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="OK"]').click()` shouldn't work. Perhaps the page isn't fully loaded when you try to obtain the element via its xpath, and in that case, you'd have to wait until that elements load via [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: Hello @NAST0R. I waited more then a minute and it keeps getting error.
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (771, 832). Other element would receive the click: <button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" style="float: right;">...</button>

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to click the wrong element, the actual clickable element could be wrapped inside an unclickable one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking at the inspect element ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpHKb.png ), I think the Button line is clickable and the Span line is not. I don´t have expecience inspecting elements, but maybe we need to find the button element above the span tag "OK". That makes sense? Do you have any idea on how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: In order to do that, right click on the button element while inspecting: from there you can copy its xpath to use in your Selenium based python script.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for helping me, but the Zvjezdan Veselinovic's solution worked like I wanted.